# Regex: get elements from a string after searched word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string :

```
const string = `       
* @body
* {
*  "test": "test"
* }
* @test
* pm.test("", function() {
* });
* @example
* {
*    "name": "test1",
*    "status": "200 OK",
*    "body": {},
*    ""
* }
* @example
* {
*    "name": "test2",
*    "status": "400",
*    "body"
* }
* 
* 
`;
```

And i would like to retrieve the passed element's content, for example if i pass as a search word `@body` i would get as an output:

```
* @body
* {
*  "test": "test"
* }
```

And if i pass `@example`, i would get as an output:

```
* @example
* {
*    "name": "test1",
*    "status": "200 OK",
*    "body": {},
*    ""
* }
* @example
* {
*    "name": "test2",
*    "status": "400",
*    "body"
* }
```

Here is my code that i'm trying :

```
string.match(/\@([^[@]+)/g)
```

and here is the output that i get :

```
[ '@body\n* {\n*  "test": "test"\n* }\n* ',
  '@test\n* pm.test("Response time is less than 200ms", function() {\n*   pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(500);\n* });\n* ',
  '@example\n* {\n*    "name": "test1",\n*    "status": "200 OK",\n*    "body": {},\n*    ""\n* }\n* ',
  '@example\n* {\n*    "name": "test2",\n*    "status": "400",\n*    "body"\n* }\n* \n* \n' ]
```

but when i add @body for example, everything get messed up.

Comment: What about `@test`?  What follows it in your example is not a closure `{ }`.  Also, didn't you post a similar question to this earlier today?

Comment: Where does this string come from? What format is it? I'm not sure RegEx are well suited for that purpose, there is certainly some parsers available

Comment: @Cid it's a string that i retrieve from a file

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen @ test will contains multiple test so there won't be a closure {}.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it was a question related to searching using a function but here i wanted to work with regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using regex match all.  We can try matching using the pattern:

```
@example[\s\S]*?(?=@|$)
```

This would get all `@example` matches.  The idea is to match `@example` followed any amount of content up to, but not including, the next `@` term *or* the end of the string (whichever comes first).

Note that I used `[\s\S]*` to simulate DOT ALL behavior, which we want, since your input spans multiple lines.

```js
var re = /@example[\s\S]*?(?=@|$)/g;
var input = "* @body\n* {\n*  \"test\": \"test\"\n* }\n* @test\n* pm.test(\"\", function() {\n* });\n* @example\n* {\n*    \"name\": \"test1\",\n*    \"status\": \"200 OK\",\n*    \"body\": {},\n*    \"\"\n* }\n* @example\n* {\n*    \"name\": \"test2\",\n*    \"status\": \"400\",\n*    \"body\"\n* }\n* \n*";
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(input);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[0]);
    }
} while (m);
```

Answer (score 1):

`getStringSection` returns the first match from the dynamic regex generated by the `part` argument passed to the method.

```js
const string = `
* @body
* {
*  "test": "test"
* }
* @test
* pm.test("", function() {
* });
* @example
* {
*    "name": "test1",
*    "status": "200 OK",
*    "body": {},
*    ""
* }
* @example
* {
*    "name": "test2",
*    "status": "400",
*    "body"
* }
* 
`
const getStringSection = part => {
  const reg = new RegExp(`@${part}[\\s\\w*."(),{};:]*`, 'gm')
  const match = string.match(reg)
  return `${string.match(reg)}`.replace('* ,', '')
}
const body = getStringSection('body')
console.log(body)
const test = getStringSection('test')
console.log(test)
const example = getStringSection('example')
console.log(example)
```